# Deploying Salesforce custome objects using MavensMate

Tags: deployment, ant, mavensmate

I do not find much information related to this topic and what I'm looking is the easy way to deploy my custom objects using MavensMate (MM).

I have meta-data of my project and I have setup with my MM but I'm lost now... how do I push the metadata to the Server (new org)? in this case salesforce.

any pointer? video, blog or help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to ensure that you are working with a MavensMate project. If it isn't yet, you need to create a MavensMate project out of the folder. See http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Existing_Projects for steps.

If it is a MM project, then check under MavensMate>Project>Edit Project to see what org and login it is using. If it is the correct org, then you can just save your files in Sublime and they'll get updated. If it is connected to a different org, then you need to do a deploy. Go to MavensMate>Deploy to Server...

Comment: I followed the steps but I do no see the option
`Select MavensMate > Create MavensMate Project.` maybe its in paid version?

Comment: There is no paid version. Is MM installed in sublime? Is there a MavensMate menu at the top of the window?

Comment: yes I did have MM installed in sublime and I do see the MM menu in the sublime.

Comment: yes I did realized after I post, its opensource

Comment: OK, so if you don't see the option to create a project, then it might already be a MM project. Is there a [project-name].sublime-project file in the directory?

Comment: yes I do see the `myproject.sublime-project`

Comment: I did go to `MM>Deploy to Server` and I do not see my custom objects in the list rather I see whatever the default objects in my org....so I have my project loaded in the MM and I edit the project and enter my credentials successfully but not seen my custom objects.

Comment: Odd, you may have to select them in the Edit Project window first. Try refreshing the schema on the Project Metadata tab and make sure your objects appear there and are checked.

Comment: yes it is odd and I have been playing around and I did Edit project window and I do not see my custom objects  and I mean how do I add the custom objects in the project so I should be able to deploy to server? I even add `<types><members>*</members><name>Work_Order__c</name></types>` in the `package.xml` but still do not see

Answer (score 1):

MavensMate isn't the only way to do this.

There are third parties, like the one I lead [Gearset](https://gearset.com), that are building speciality deployment tools.

For custom objects, we will build the dependency tree to bring along any Profile or PermissionSet changes.

You can see a small video of it in action [here](https://gearset.com/blog/migrating-salesforce-changes-with-gearset-deploy)

Comment: I have just downloaded and its so slow you don't feel like working with this tool, why is it so slow? i have the fastest computer with 24 gb ram

Comment: Sorry to hear it is being a pain for you! Which part of it is slow, the actual downloading of metadata or something else? We use the same metadata APIs as ant/mavens so should be no slower. Fancy sending me a mail kevin@gearset.com to talk through it?

Comment: once its load the metadata i can not click the checkbox or click the tab its freezes and my memory usage goes upto 80% and I have to kill the task, sorry I end-up uninstalling the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, looks like we have some work to do around performance! Do you want to help us out and do a remote debugging session so we can see what is going wrong?